# Is exams2canvas compatible with Canvas New Quiz format?

Tags: r-exams

I'm using the R-exams package to create Canvas quizzes, and can successfully import the zip file of quizzes exported from R via exams2canvas() as "Classic Quizzes" into Canvas. However, when I import them as "New Quizzes", whilst the import states "Completed", there is some sort of error as no questions are available in the Quiz.

My main concern is that Canvas will start to withdraw Classic Quizzes in October 2021, so I'll need to change to the new format.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

We have not looked into that in detail, yet. We plan to make the necessary adaptions to `exams2canvas()` but couldn't test this yet.

According to the official [New Quizzes Timeline](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/New-Quizzes-Users/New-Quizzes-Timeline-Overview/ta-p/243647) the New Quizzes will be enabled in July 2021 "in all courses in paid accounts" and then "New Quizzes and Classic Quizzes can be used in tandem". Hence my understanding is that classic quizzes will not be deprecated immediately.

#### Details

*Classic Quizzes* in Canvas only supported the old QTI 1.2 XML format for imports. *New Quizzes* can import both the old QTI 1.2 XML format and the newer QTI 2.1 XML format. Both of these are supported by the R/exams package in functions `exams2qti12()` and `exams2qti21()`.

However, devil is in the detail. Within a certain XML standard like QTI you still have a lot of flexibility how exactly to specify certain aspects of a quiz. For example, the learning management systems OLAT (prior to version 12 or so), ILIAS, and Canvas (with classic quizzes) all rely on QTI 1.2. However, they use require slightly different flavors of it. Therefore, `exams2qti12()` has a `flavor` argument and there are dedicated custom interfaces for `exams2ilias()` and `exams2canvas()`.

Therefore, for the *New Quizzes* I expect that we need to make certain tweaks to either `exams2qti12()` and/or `exams2qti21()` to get these properly supported. Unfortunately, so far we were not able to test these because the community server by Instructure at https://canvas.instructure.com/ does not incorporate *New Quizzes* yet. And that's what we rely on for our Canvas testing because we don't have our own Canvas system installed. Given the information in the official timeline, I expect that we can start testing this on the community server in summer 2021.

Comment: Just as an update: As of January 2022, the community server provided by Instructure still does not support New Quizzes. So we can still not test this and adapt `exams2canvas()` suitably.

Comment: Is there a 2024 update on this topic? It would be a great added value to support cloze.

Comment: The community server provided by Instructure STILL does not support New Quizzes. However, colleagues from institutions using Canvas were so nice to provide guest accounts for us. So we can finally test. Moreover, recently Instructure added the possibility to export New Quizzes to QTI: https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Instructor-Guide/How-do-I-export-a-New-Quiz-from-a-course/ta-p/580322 This showed that New Quizzes are still in QTI 1.2 format (not 2.x) and that the differences in the config file are not too huge. So we'll try to trace down the remaining problems...

Comment: Any updates on export for exams2canvas for new quizzes?

Comment: Not in the last two weeks (since my comment above). My coauthor Niki Umlauf has tried various changes but none of them were successful unfortunately. We will keep trying!

Comment: Thank you very much for the update, keep looking forward to updates from your side. Let's hope they do not turn off classic quizzes anytime soon. Or at least until New Quizzes are "fixed"

Comment: They announced a couple of times that they would turn of Classic Quizzes but never went through with it. My feeling is that it still would be very hard for them to switch off the Classic Quiz support soon because a lot of users (not only from R/exams) are still depending on it. But I don't have any more tangible information regarding this...

Answer (score 2):

`exams2qti21()` works for `schoice` and `mchoice` question types in the new Canvas quiz format.  You need get rid of the a.b.c.d in the answers to allow for shuffling.  New quizzes should be able to handle the `cloze` question format.