# difficulty using r/exams exams2qti21 for canvas new quizzes

Tags: r-exams

Has anyone had luck importing an r/exams QTI into Canvas "New Quizzes", or is an update forthcoming that would enable this? I saw this thread, [Is exams2canvas compatible with Canvas New Quiz format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788061/is-exams2canvas-compatible-with-canvas-new-quiz-format), but haven't found any updates since. Classic quizzes are scheduled to be deprecated this coming summer 2022. I am able to "import" the qti21 format (in that it doesn't throw an error), but the image files are all missing and much of the math is rendered incorrectly.

Comment: So far the community server from Instructure _still_ does not support New Quizzes, so we still cannot test this functionality. What you can play around with in QTI 2.1 the HTML `converter` and the `base64` coding. The ollowing would correspond to the settings in `exams2canvas`: `exams2qti21(..., converter = "pandoc-mathml", base64 = FALSE)`.

Comment: Did you try to play around with this? Does it change anything in the way images and/or mathematical equations are rendered? I just had another look at the official tutorials on how to migrate classic quizzes to new quizzes - and all of that unfortunately is not supported on Instructure's community server that we rely on for testing.

Comment: Sorry I had to ditch new quizzes due to this issue so have been using classic for now, and have been swamped with the current semester! I just tried with these settings, and the base64 = FALSE gives errors (not very helpful ones), and won't load at all. Specifying pandoc-mathml doesn't throw an error, but after it "imports" there are no questions in the quiz.

Comment: Thanks for trying and reporting the results! We will have to have a closer look when we finally get access to a new quizzes Canvas somewhere... Thanks!

Comment: I could invite you to my "practice" course if that would help, just let me know. I will send you an email at the general info contact account on the r/exams page, but let me know if there is a better way to get in touch.

Comment: Sorry @eiselab for not following up here, I just noticed this today. Meanwhile we have access to Canvas instances provides export of New Quizzes but we haven't been successful, yet, adapting our `exams2qti12()` code for it. Devil appears to be in the detail...and there still isn't any documentation as far as I know. Some discussions have also been going on in the older thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788061/is-exams2canvas-compatible-with-canvas-new-quiz-format I think it is best if you close this thread a duplicate of the older one.

Comment: @AchimZeileis OK, do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it? There aren't any answers to actually accept/close the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is exams2canvas compatible with Canvas New Quiz format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788061/is-exams2canvas-compatible-with-canvas-new-quiz-format)

Comment: I have now voted to close it as a duplicate. Just closing it would be fine as well I think.